# magento 1.9 Standalone php file on root folder not working

Tags: magento-1.9

I looked on internet and found the below code is the way to create a standalone file on magento root folder.

```
<?php 
     require_once('app/Mage.php');
     ini_set('display_errors', 1);
     Mage::app('admin');
?>
```

But When I run the file on browser it gives the following error. https://prnt.sc/hxjulx
I looked in system.log folder and exception.log folder, but no error related to it is shown.
I thought it may be due to server problem but my website is working fine.
I could not find what is wrong with this file. Any one can tell me where I could look for the error or what could be wrong.

Comment: go to index.php file and search for ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
You need to uncomment this code so you will get actual error. That will be helpful to you to find error solution.

Comment: I looked into index.php file and this line is already uncommented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information on `HTTP ERROR 500` should be logged to your server's log files in more detail as well so you may want to take a look in there (location depends on your setup but `/var/log/` or `/var/www/path/to/your/webspace/log` is a good starting point).

Other than that, since your code seems valid the only way I can reproduce your issue is when the path to `app/Mage.php` is incorrect (i.e. if your test script is not located in the Magento root directory), so you may try to specify the absolute path instead.